# SQL Job: How to start with?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

Can anyone help me to create an SQL job in SQL server Agent (SQL 2008) ,which will run in a purticular time interval(Ex: Daily) and select records from a table with status=1 (select name,age from student)and pass to another stored procedure which accepts student name and age

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: If you are using Express edition, the SQL Agent is not available. Could taht be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I would take:

**Create the script**

- Create a SQL script with a CURSOR in it (the only reason I say cursor is because you are passing Student Name and Age to a different stored procedure)
- Read the StudentName and Age into @variables
- Execute the stored proc with appropriate parameters
- Fetch next row and loop
- **IMP**: TEST the script

Save the script in a SQL file for further reference.

**In SQL Server Agent**

- Create a new job
- point it to the appropriate database
- Paste the SQL Script (from above) into the script area of the job
- Create an appropriate schedule (daily, at 3:15 am)
- If operators and SQL Mail are setup, add those so that you can get email notifications
- Save the job
- **IMP**: TEST the job